# How to cycle through DIVs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want my page to show 3 divs at a time, and when I click next I would like it to show the next 3 divs.  Then when I click previous, I would like to display the previous 3.

```
$("#container .result").slice(0, 3).show();

   $("#right").click(function () {

       var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().last();

       var nextItems = items.nextAll().slice(0, 3);

       if (nextItems.length === 0) {
           nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);
       }

       nextItems.show();
   });
   $("#left").click(function () {

       var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().last();

       var nextItems = items.prevAll().slice(0, 3);

       if (nextItems.length === 0) {
           nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);
       }

       nextItems.show();
   });
```

The problem is that when I click previous, and it comes to last 3 divs and when I click again it shows 2 than 1. How can i fix that? I want it to stop when it comes to first 3.

Comment: Or to loop again, for example i have 9 divs, when it come to last 3 and click previous to show last 3.

Comment: you may need a variable to keep track of your current location.  You're code always gets the first 3 items, instead of 3 items relative to your current position in the set

Comment: how can i do that? Sorry i am no expert in jquery? @GlennFerrie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very much on the right track, I was impressed by the ingenuity of your code.

Your main problem is solved with a very simple fix; in the `#left` click-handler, replace `.last()` with `.first()`:

```
var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().first();
```

And to loop around to the last 3 when you click previous on the first 3, change this line to the next:

```
nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);

nextItems = $("#container .result").slice($("#container .result").length-3, $("#container .result").length);
```

---

But I thought the situation might occur, now or in the future, that the number of `.result`s aren't a multitude of `3`, let's say `7` or `11` for example.
I created a script that will handle that, and also loop around in both directions:

```
$("#container .result").first().show(); //initialize divs at pageload
$(".nav").click(function() {
  var start=0, step=3;
  var currentItems = $("#container .result:visible").hide();
  var currentLast = (this.id==="prev" ? currentItems.first() : currentItems.last());
  var nextItems = (this.id==="prev" ? currentLast.prevAll() : currentLast.nextAll());

  if (nextItems.length === 0) { //if the last set of divs has been reached, loop around
    var itemsLength = $("#container .result").length;
    if (this.id==="prev") {start=itemsLength-step; step=itemsLength;} //determine wich way to loop around
    nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(start,step); //loop around
  } else if (nextItems.length < step) { //if the next divs aren't a full set, keep some divs from the current set visible
    if (this.id==="prev") {step-=nextItems.length;} else {start=nextItems.length;} //determine which current items should remain visible
    currentItems.slice(start,step).each(function(){nextItems.push(this);}); //add selected current items to nextItems-array
  } else {nextItems=nextItems.slice(start,step);} //if the next divs are a full set, simply select the next set
  nextItems.show(); //show the next set
}).click(); //initialize divs at pageload
```

- In HTML, I gave the two buttons both a class `"nav"` *(see code snippet below)*, so that I could combine their click-handlers into one.
- I changed your first line to this: `$("#container .result").first().show();`. That line - in combination with the `.click()` chained to the click-handler - replaces your line: `$("#container .result").slice(0, 3).show();` (at the top of your script).
  This gives you much more flexibility to change the amount of `div`s you want to show on the page at once. At the start of the click-handler I declare `var step=3;`, which is the only place that number is hard-coded, so if you ever want to change the amount you only have to change that number (and maybe adjust some styling).
- The rest of the explanation is in the comments in the code.

---

See the ***code snippet*** below for a demo:

```js
$("#container .result").first().show(); //initialize divs at pageload
$(".nav").click(function() {
  var start=0, step=3;
  var currentItems = $("#container .result:visible").hide();
  var currentLast = (this.id==="prev" ? currentItems.first() : currentItems.last());
  var nextItems = (this.id==="prev" ? currentLast.prevAll() : currentLast.nextAll());
  
  if (nextItems.length === 0) { //if the last set of divs has been reached, loop around
    var itemsLength = $("#container .result").length;
    if (this.id==="prev") {start=itemsLength-step; step=itemsLength;} //determine wich way to loop around
    nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(start,step); //loop around
  } else if (nextItems.length < step) { //if the next divs aren't a full set, keep some divs from the current set visible
    if (this.id==="prev") {step-=nextItems.length;} else {start=nextItems.length;} //determine which current items should remain visible
    currentItems.slice(start,step).each(function(){nextItems.push(this);}); //add selected current items to nextItems-array
  } else {nextItems=nextItems.slice(start,step);} //if the next divs are a full set, simply select the next set
  nextItems.show(); //show the next set
}).click(); //initialize divs at pageload
```

```css
html,body {width:98%; height:90%;}

#container {width:100%; height:90%; background:lightgrey;}
#container .result {display:none; float:left; width:30%; height:100%; margin:0 1.66%; background:lightgreen;}
#container .result > div {display:table; width:100%; height:100%;}
#container .result > div > div {display:table-cell; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; font:bolder 2em sans-serif;}

.nav {margin-top:2%; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="result"><div><div>1</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>2</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>3</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>4</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>5</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>6</div></div></div>
  <div class="result"><div><div>7</div></div></div>
</div>
<button type="button" class="nav" id="prev">PREVIOUS</button>
<button type="button" class="nav" id="next">NEXT</button>
```

**codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQoJzd?editors=1010**
**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k8ysj6gq/1/**

- You can ignore the CSS and HTML (except for the `class="nav"` on the buttons), that's all just so we can see it. All the relevant code is in the JS.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do something like below.
On Next or Previous click set `margin-left` of container to position or loop through all div.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.next-button').on('click', function() {
    if (parseInt($('.carousel-item').css("margin-left").slice(0, -2)) < -2000) {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "0px"
      }, 200)
    } else {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "-=600px"
      }, 200);
    }
  });


  $('.prev-button').on('click', function() {
    if (parseInt($('.carousel-item').css("margin-left").slice(0, -2)) > 0) {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "-2000px"
      }, 200)
    } else {
      $('.carousel-item').animate({
        "margin-left": "+=600px"
      }, 200);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.carousel-container {
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  margin: 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 720px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: center;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  padding: 0;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -o-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -o-box;
  display: box;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px #333;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.item>a {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.prev-button,
.next-button {
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: gray;
}

.navigation {
  width: 60px;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.next-button:hover,
.prev-button:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.navigation:active {
  color: white;
}

.next-button {
  right: 0;
}

.prev-button {
  left: 0;
}


/* .carousel-item li:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('http://urbanphenomena.net/imgs/cover/bq2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
} */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="carousel-container">
  <a class="prev-button navigation" href="#">
    <</a>
      &nbsp;
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 1 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 2 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 3 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 4 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 5 </a></li>

        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 6 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 7 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 8 </a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#"> 9 </a></li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#"> </a>
        </li>
      </div>
      &nbsp;
      <a class="next-button navigation" href="#">></a>
</div>
Run co
```

Comment: `click next it show next 3 divs`? Your snippet shows the next div but not next 3. Please update your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so your first mistake was that when trying to code back 3 you were getting the previous 3 items from the first of the 3 not the last. So i changed .last() to .first(). Then to loop back when previous = 0 all you did was slice from the current 3, instead of slicing at the end of the entire array of elements.

Here's a link to a codepen that has the working code(you'll obviously have to change the variables to fit your project): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjzxee?editors=1010

changed `var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().last();` to `var items = $('#container .result:visible').hide().first();`

and

```
if (nextItems.length === 0) {
       nextItems = $("#container .result").slice(0, 3);
   }
```

to

```
if (nextItems.length === 0) {
       var allItems =  $("#container .result");
       nextItems = $("li").slice(allItems.length - 3,allItems.length);
   }
```

this also only works if the number elements is a multiple of the number you are skipping each time, but i can fix that if you'd like

Comment: Colby.. Thanks for the code pen example! I've been looking for a solution like this for about 2 days.